# Merge classes from parent component to child component root element in Solid JS

Tags: jsx, solid-js

I want to be able to add classes from a parent component to the child component root element in Solid JS like this:

```js
const A = () => {
  return <div class="a">whatever</div>
}
const B = () => {
  return <A class="b" />
}
// <B /> should render <div class="a b">whatever</div>
```

This doesn't work.
I can sure change `A` to be like

```js
const A = (props) => {
  return <div class={`a ${props.class || ''}`}>whatever</div>
}
```

but what would I have to do if I couldn't (e.g. if `A` came from a component library)?
I have thought of render highjacking with a higher order component as is possible in class-based React but not sure how that could work in Solid (apart from the fact that render highjacking is quite a dirty hack in my honest opinion)

So what I need is something that works like

```js
const classesForwarder = (component) => (props) => { /* How? */ }
const B = classesForwarder(() => <A class="b" />)
```

Is it even possible to add a class to the root element of a component from the parent if the child component author did not provide the option?

Comment: solid rendering happens in the leaves and only the result (real DOM nodes) are being passed to the parent. So either the library supports it, or you can consider that a bug and report an issue to the component lib. The only way to fix that in userspace without forking the library is to add the class directly to the received dom node, but that won't work with SSR

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your child component accepts class names as props, if so, string manipulations should work.

If child does not accept classes as props, your example should not work in React either. But either way, it is not something that can be worked around:

```js
import { Component } from "solid-js";

export const Parent: Component<{}> = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Child class="from-parent" />
    </div>
  );
};

export const Child: Component<{ class: string }> = (props) => {
  return (
    <div class={props.class}>Child Component</div>
  );
};

export const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Parent />
    </div>
  );
};
```

https://playground.solidjs.com/anonymous/7a39875c-39a0-47a4-8d08-05345ca23cc7

You can merge parent and child classes if both accept class names:

```js
import { Component } from "solid-js";

export const Parent: Component<{ class: string }> = (props) => {
  return (
    <div class={props.class}>
      Parent Component
      <Child class={props.class} />
    </div>
  );
};

export const Child: Component<{ class: string }> = (props) => {
  return (
    <div class={[props.class, "child-class"].join(' ')}>Child Component</div>
  );
};

export const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Parent class="parent-class" />
    </div>
  );
};
```

If not, Solid provides HOC pattern similar to React's:

```js
import { children, Component, createEffect, JSXElement, onMount } from "solid-js";

export const Parent: Component<{ children: JSXElement }> = (props) => {
  const resolved = children(() => props.children);
  
  createEffect(() => {
    console.log(typeof resolved());
    (resolved() as HTMLElement).classList.add('from-parent');
  });

  return (
    <div>{resolved()}</div>
  );
};

export const Child: Component<{}> = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>Child Component</div>
  );
};

export const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Parent><Child /></Parent>
    </div>
  );
};
```

https://playground.solidjs.com/anonymous/655b7148-d041-4ba7-9b47-7e6735315ab2

NOTE: This works in browser without any problem but have issues inside Solid Playground. I don't know the exact cause of the problem, but Playground has some quirks and it is not the first time we have such problems.

You can read more about this pattern: https://www.solidjs.com/docs/latest#children

If child does not allow passing class names, but forwards ref, you can control child's class name via that ref.

```js
import { Component, onMount } from "solid-js";

export const Parent: Component<{}> = (props) => {
  let child: HTMLDivElement;

  onMount(() => {
    child.classList.add('from-parent');
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <Child ref={child!} />
    </div>
  );
};

export const Child: Component<{ ref: HTMLDivElement }> = (props) => {
  return (
    <div ref={props.ref}>Child Component</div>
  );
};

export const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Parent />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Please note that the above code works in browser but has problem in Solid Playground. The order of component execution is somehow slightly different in the playground. But you can wrap child component inside an if statement to prevent error:

```
 onMount(() => {
  if (child) {
    child.classList.add('from-parent');
  }
 });
```

Another alternative would be using query selectors:

```js
import { Component, onMount } from "solid-js";

export const Parent: Component<{}> = (props) => {
  let ref: HTMLDivElement;

  onMount(() => {
    const child = ref.querySelector('div');
    if (child) {
      console.log(child);
      child.classList.add('from-parent');
    }
  });

  return (
    <div ref={ref!}>
      <Child />
    </div>
  );
};

export const Child: Component<{}> = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>Child Component</div>
  );
};

export const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Parent />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Solid is more permissible and predictable that React. I believe there is nothing you can do in React but in Solid. Since they have different premises, solutions do not translate directly.